# Q: Efficient modular arithmetic in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm building some modules in VHDL for handling modular arithmetic and want to make sure it's well-designed for timing and somewhat efficient when scaling up. This will need to work with 128-bit or 256-bit arithmetic when complete, but I'm testing it currently with small 16-bit numbers currently. There are two modules, mod_add for the basic modular arithmetic, and mod_mul for the multiplication built on top of modular addition.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity mod_add is
    generic(
        bits : positive := 16;
        modulo : positive := 15
    );
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        rst : in std_logic;
        a : in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
        b : in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
        q : out std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0) := (others => '0')
    );
end entity;

architecture behavior of mod_add is
    constant modulo_c : std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(modulo, bits));
    signal q_int : std_logic_vector(bits downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal q_out : std_logic_vector(bits downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if rst = '1' then
                q_int <= (others => '0');
                q_out <= (others => '0');
            else
                q_int <= std_logic_vector(unsigned("0" & a) + unsigned("0" & b));
                if unsigned(q_int) >= unsigned("0" & modulo_c) then
                    q_out <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(q_int) - unsigned(modulo_c));
                else
                    q_out <= q_int;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    q <= q_out(bits-1 downto 0);
end architecture behavior;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity mod_mul is
   generic(
        bits : positive := 16;
        modulo : positive := 15
    );
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        rst : in std_logic;
        load : in std_logic;
        ready : out std_logic := '0';
        a : in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
        b : in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
        q : out std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0) := (others => '0')
    );
end entity;

architecture behavior of mod_mul is
    component mod_add
        generic(
                 bits : positive := 16;
                 modulo : positive := 15
             );
             port(
                 clk : in std_logic;
                 rst : in std_logic;
                 a : in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
                 b : in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
                 q : out std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0)
             );
    end component mod_add;

    constant p_c : std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(modulo, bits));
    signal q_int : std_logic_vector(bits downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal q_out : std_logic_vector(bits downto 0) := (others => '0');

    constant b_zero : std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal b_shift : std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal culm : std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal val : std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal culm_add_val : std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal val_double : std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal counter : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := "00";
begin
    culm_add_val_proc: mod_add generic map(
        bits => bits,
        modulo => modulo
    ) port map(
        clk => clk,
        rst => rst,
        a => culm,
        b => val,
        q => culm_add_val
    );

    val_double_proc: mod_add generic map(
        bits => bits,
        modulo => modulo
    ) port map(
        clk => clk,
        rst => rst,
        a => val,
        b => val,
        q => val_double
    );

    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if rst = '1' then
                counter <= (others => '0');
            elsif load = '1' then
                counter <= (others => '0');
            else
                counter <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(counter) + 1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if rst = '1' then
                culm <= (others => '0');
                val <= (others => '0');
            elsif load = '1' then
                culm <= (others => '0');
                val <= a;
                b_shift <= b;
            elsif counter = "10" then
                if b_shift(0) = '1' then
                    culm <= culm_add_val;
                end if;
                val <= val_double;
                b_shift <= "0" & b_shift(bits-1 downto 1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    q <= culm;
    ready <= '1' when b_shift = b_zero else '0';
end architecture behavior;
```

And the test bench for mod_mul:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity test_mod_mul is
end entity test_mod_mul;

architecture behavioral of test_mod_mul is
    component mod_mul
        generic(
            bits : positive := 16;
            modulo : positive := 15
        );
        port(
            clk : in std_logic;
            rst : in std_logic;
            load : in std_logic;
            ready : out std_logic;
            a : in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
            b : in std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0);
            q : out std_logic_vector(bits-1 downto 0)
        );
    end component mod_mul;

    constant clk_period : time := 20 ns;
    signal halt : boolean := false;

    signal clk : std_logic := '0';
    signal rst : std_logic := '0';
    signal load : std_logic := '0';
    signal a, b : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal a_in, b_in : integer := 0;

    signal ready : std_logic;
    signal q : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal q_out : integer;
begin
    uut: mod_mul port map(
        clk => clk,
        rst => rst,
        load => load,
        ready => ready,
        a => a,
        b => b,
        q => q
    );

    a <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(a_in, a'length));
    b <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(b_in, b'length));
    q_out <= to_integer(unsigned(q));

    process
    begin
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        if halt then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

    process
        procedure check_multiply(
            constant a, b : in integer;
            constant q : in integer) is
        begin
            wait until falling_edge(clk);
            a_in <= a;
            b_in <= b;
            load <= '1';
            wait for clk_period;
            load <= '0';
            wait until rising_edge(clk) and ready = '1';
            assert q_out = q report "Failed mod multiplication" severity error;
        end procedure check_multiply;
    begin
        rst <= '1';
        wait for 10*clk_period;
        rst <= '0';
        wait for clk_period;
        assert ready = '1' report "Not ready" severity error;
        assert q_out = 0 report "Failed mod multiplication" severity failure;

        check_multiply(2, 2, 4);
        check_multiply(2, 3, 6);
        check_multiply(3, 3, 9);
        check_multiply(4, 4, 1);
        check_multiply(6, 5, 0);
        check_multiply(6, 7, 12);

        wait for 1000 ns;
        halt <= true;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture behavioral;
```

Comment: Can I ask what you are designing? ASIC? FPGA? What synthesis tools are you using? What arithmetic functions do you want to realize (in equations)?